# ffmpeg not recognized

Tags: command-line, software-installation, ffmpeg

I am having a problem with ffmpeg. I had it installed and then installed 14.10. I reinstalled it, but I am getting this error message.

[image: ffmpeg]

Also, I went to this website https://superuser.com/questions/858874/ffmpeg-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libass-so-4-cannot-open-shared-obj/858884#858884.

It talked about someone who was having a similar problem. However, when I tried the last step (sudo apt-get install libass4) I came up with this error message.

[image: ffmpeg2]

Is there a work around. Thank you all in advance, I appreciate your efforts to help me.

Comment: have you tried this? http://superuser.com/a/858884

Comment: Yes I did,I will show you the error message in an edit to my question.

Comment: 14.10 uses libass5, not libass4. Also there is no ffmpeg in 14.10 so where did you get it?

Comment: Yes libass5 is installed, but I am getting this errormessage for libass4.I found this website:http://www.noobslab.com/2014/12/ffmpeg-returns-to-ubuntu-1410.html.

Comment: `ffmpeg` can still be installed via PPAs or by compiling from source.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan I decided to try and compile it, looks like it's working now. If you make this an answer I will vote on it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that I just attempted and it seems to work -

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libass.so.5 libass.so.4
ffmpeg -formats (should now work)
```